# Can't copy a value from one worksheet over to an array in another worksheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

In the same workbook, I've got two worksheets: Model and Results.

My goal is to copy the value of a cell in *Model* (for e.g., F8) over to a cell in an array (c4 to I23) in *Results* called ResultsArray (see code below).

When I run my module, no error appears, but the code doesnt seem to work either (the value of F8 doesnt get copied over to the specified cell in ResultsArray).

Appreciate any help.

Tried running different variations of the code below

```
Sub CopyTest()

Dim ResultsArray As Variant
ResultsArray = Worksheets("Results").Range("C4:I23")
    
ResultsArray(1, 1) = Worksheets("Model").Range("F8").Value

End Sub
```

I'm using ResultsArray(1,1) because I am hoping to introduce a loop into the code to populate cells in the array based on the loop counter, e.g., ResultsArray(loopcounter,1)

Comment: It seems to work. Can you test the result of the array at the end via: MsgBox (ResultsArray(1, 1)). Let me know what returns.

Comment: You never assign any value to the other sheet - if you want the first element of  `ResultsArray` to go to F8 you need something like `Worksheets("Model").Range("F8").Value = ResultsArray(1, 1)`

Comment: @TimWilliams I actually want to do the opposite: to assign the value of F8 in the "Model" sheet to the first element in ResultsArray

Comment: If you load an array from a range, and then update the array, the range values are not updated - you would need to write the array back to the range after the update: `Worksheets("Results").Range("C4:I23").Value = ResultsArray `

Answer (score -1):

So turns out I just needed to add "Set" in the 2nd line before "ResultsArray" when assigning the range from the worksheet "Model" to it:

```
Sub CopyTest()

Dim ResultsArray As Variant
Set ResultsArray = Worksheets("Results").Range("C4:I23")

ResultsArray(1, 1) = Worksheets("Model").Range("F8").Value

End Sub
```

I've tested this addition and it works

Comment: You need to differentiate an array from a range. You are just dealing in ranges so something like this would be appropriate: `Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Worksheets("Results").Range("C4:I23"): rg.Cells(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("Model").Range("F8").Value` which means that you are copying to the first cell of your range. When you use As Variant, as you initially did, you are assigning the values from the range to an array, think of it as another worksheet but in memory. 
 Watch [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7ScsebMq5uXrWfpZ-iJ2LKI6G9k0khQZ) to understand what arrays are.